# How to set appearance settings for a specific screen?

Tags: macos, dark-mode

Is there a way to display the app on a specific screen always in light mode while simultaneously ensuring that the app follows the system appearance settings when its window is moved to another screen without restarting the app? The screen in question is an e-ink monitor, and it is more convenient to use it in light mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set an app to use Light Mode, but that will apply to every window of the app.

```
defaults write -app nameOfApp AppleInterfaceStyle -string "Light"
```